# Set custom permission to guest user for accessory in HomeKit

Tags: ios, iphone, homekit

I have created the guest user for a home using Apple's HomeKit framework. Guest user is now can read and write characteristics of appliance.
 My question is how to set custom permission for the guest user. i.e. I don't want guest user to be change the characteristics value for particular appliance.
 Also is their any Apple documentation explaining the permission.
 I have gone through link : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/HomeKitDeveloperGuide/ManagingUsers/ManagingUsers.html

Comment: may be it will be helpful             HMUser *adminOrNot = [selectedHome currentUser];
            HMHomeAccessControl *homeContr = [selectedHome homeAccessControlForUser:adminOrNot];
            
            if(homeContr.administrator)
            {
}else{ }

Comment: selectedHome object of class HMHome doesn't have any APIs like currentUser, homeAccessControlForUser,etc

Comment: you need to target ios 9+

Answer (score 0):

There is very limited user access control for accessories. Apple has defined a standard characteristic type, Admin only access, that you can set to prohibit any users who are not the admin from interacting with the accessory, but that's an accessory level limitation (rather than being enforced in the homekit API). As such, it requires the accessory implement support for that characteristic.

Other more complex schemes are possible, but require specific accessory support, i.e. the accessory maker would need to create some sort of API to manage user access. To my knowledge, no accessories currently support this, and there isn't anything standard from apple (yet).

Answer (score 0):

In the HomeKit Accessory simulator you can simulate a device that has this by adding a characteristic to your device that has the type HMCharacteristicTypeAdminOnlyAccess and set the value to true. Otherwise the device manufacturer needs to add this characteristic in their service.